# Getting attribute from list

Tags: javascript, html

I have this sidebar with 3 list items:

HTML:

```
<div id="sideMenu" >
    <ul class="bmenu">
        <li id="f1" onclick="style1()">Style 1</li> <!--turn sidebar on/off-->
        <li id='f2' onclick="style2()">Style 2</li> <!--randomize vidcontain border-->
        <li id='f3' onclick="style3()">Style 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to set a var which will contain the ID of which ever list item I select so I can store it for later use.

Could I accomplish this use javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare it:

```
var selectedStyle;
```

...and then within your `styleX` functions, you set it:

```
function style1() {
    selectedStyle = "f1";
}
```

Note, though, that you don't have to have separate `style1`, `style2`, and `style3` functions if you don't want to. If you change your `onclick` to:

```
onclick="setStyle(this)"
```

...then your `setStyle` function can use the DOM element that gets passed into it, which has an `id` property on it containing the `id` of the element (since I notice all of your elements using the `onclick` have `id` values):

```
function setStyle(elm) {
    selectedStyle = elm.id;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really change anything does it? Is it just a more efficient way of writing the code? I dont think I understand how it would know which function I want to run based on those changes. I'll try the first part of your solution though to see if that helps me solve my current problem

Comment: @Batman: The idea of the `setStyle` thing is that I assume the logic of setting the style is basically the same for all three styles, just with different values. So using a single function that chooses the values based on `elm.id` (which will be `"f1"`, `"f2"`, or `"f3"` depending on which element was clicked) might be more efficient. But obviously it depends on what `style1`, `style2`, etc. actually do.

Comment: They're pretty similar, just changing a few elements here and there: http://jsfiddle.net/z9jkB/  But the web storage API is what the focus of this assignment is so I probably won't changing the onclick functions. Im more concerned with trying to figure out how to have the style changes saved locally so when i refresh the page the same stlye is applied. If you can help me out with that, it would be amazing.